# Query takes 20+ seconds, table is less than 300 rows

Tags: sql

Here's the query:

```
  with contrib as (
    select
      first_name,
      last_name,
      user_id,
      photo_url
    from contributors
    where visible = true
    group by 1,2,3,4
  ),
  dwm as (
    select * from dialogues_with_metadata
  ),
  joined as (
    select
      c.*,
      dwm.dialogue_id
    from contrib c
    left join dwm on c.user_id = dwm.contributor_one_user_id or c.user_id = dwm.contributor_two_user_id
  )
  select
    first_name,
    last_name,
    user_id,
    photo_url,
    count(distinct dialogue_id) as dialogues
  from joined
  group by 1,2,3,4
  order by 3 desc
```

PostgreSQL database.

CPU usage is 10%, so I don't think that's the problem!

I suspect what's slowing things down is the join statement. How might I reconfigure this query so that it doesn't take ~20 seconds to return less than 300 rows?

Here's the contributors table schema:

```
user_id (primary key - uuid)
username
first_name
last_name
hash
description
blurb
photo_url
blurb_updated_at
visible
```

And the dialogues table schema:

```
dialogue_id (uuid)
contributor_one_uuid
contributor_two_uuid
title
image_url
visible
categories
image_source
current_popularity
created_at
override_url
visible
```

Ran `explain select * from dialogues_with_metadata;` Here are the results:

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=167.80..172.34 rows=137 width=880)
  Hash Cond: (a.dialogue_id = b.writing_dialogue_id)
  CTE main
    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=64.30..111.60 rows=137 width=504)
          Hash Cond: (c2.user_id = d.contributor_two_uuid)
          ->  Seq Scan on contributors c2  (cost=0.00..43.60 rows=260 width=125)
          ->  Hash  (cost=62.59..62.59 rows=137 width=325)
                ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=46.85..62.59 rows=137 width=325)
                      Hash Cond: (d.contributor_one_uuid = c1.user_id)
                      ->  Seq Scan on dialogues d  (cost=0.00..15.37 rows=137 width=216)
                      ->  Hash  (cost=43.60..43.60 rows=260 width=125)
                            ->  Seq Scan on contributors c1  (cost=0.00..43.60 rows=260 width=125)
  CTE dialogues_with_installment_counts
    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=50.39..52.00 rows=129 width=28)
          Group Key: writings.dialogue_id
          ->  Seq Scan on writings  (cost=0.00..46.82 rows=476 width=28)
                Filter: finalized
  ->  CTE Scan on main a  (cost=0.00..2.74 rows=137 width=868)
  ->  Hash  (cost=2.58..2.58 rows=129 width=28)
        ->  CTE Scan on dialogues_with_installment_counts b  (cost=0.00..2.58 rows=129 width=28)
```

EXPLAIN on updated query:

```
Seq Scan on contributors c  (cost=0.00..4012.89 rows=247 width=109)
  Filter: visible
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=16.06..16.07 rows=1 width=8)
          ->  Seq Scan on dialogues  (cost=0.00..16.05 rows=2 width=0)
                Filter: ((c.user_id = contributor_one_uuid) OR (c.user_id = contributor_two_uuid))
```

`explain (analyze, buffers) select` on updated query:

```
Seq Scan on contributors c  (cost=0.00..4205.86 rows=259 width=109) (actual time=0.073..16819.258 rows=260 loops=1)
  Filter: visible
  Rows Removed by Filter: 13
  Buffers: shared hit=3681
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=16.06..16.07 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=64.548..64.549 rows=1 loops=260)
          Buffers: shared hit=3640
          ->  Seq Scan on dialogues  (cost=0.00..16.05 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=49.155..64.547 rows=1 loops=260)
                Filter: ((c.user_id = contributor_one_uuid) OR (c.user_id = contributor_two_uuid))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 136
                Buffers: shared hit=3640
Planning Time: 0.136 ms
Execution Time: 16819.365 ms
```

A second time (16 seconds faster!):

```
Seq Scan on contributors c  (cost=0.00..4205.86 rows=259 width=109) (actual time=0.063..801.278 rows=260 loops=1)
  Filter: visible
  Rows Removed by Filter: 13
  Buffers: shared hit=3681
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=16.06..16.07 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=3.080..3.080 rows=1 loops=260)
          Buffers: shared hit=3640
          ->  Seq Scan on dialogues  (cost=0.00..16.05 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.009..3.079 rows=1 loops=260)
                Filter: ((c.user_id = contributor_one_uuid) OR (c.user_id = contributor_two_uuid))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 136
                Buffers: shared hit=3640
Planning Time: 0.127 ms
Execution Time: 801.379 ms
```

Comment: mysql, postgresql, or what sql ? And why contributors are grouped by ? user_id is unique as I see

Comment: Please add the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query to your question

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the same without unnesesary grouping statements

```
   select
      c.first_name,
      c.last_name,
      c.user_id,
      c.photo_url,
      (
        select 
          count(distinct dialogue_id) from dialogues_with_metadata dwm
        where
          c.user_id = dwm.contributor_one_user_id 
          or c.user_id = dwm.contributor_two_user_id
      ) as dialogues
      from contributors c
        where c.visible = true
```

Additionaly it's worth checking if counting number of conversations can be done in more efficient way (what indexes are on this table ?).

Query version with `dialogues` table

```
   select
      c.first_name,
      c.last_name,
      c.user_id,
      c.photo_url,
      (
        select 
          count(*) from dialogues
        where
          c.user_id = dialogues.contributor_one_uuid 
          or c.user_id = dialogues.contributor_two_uuid
      ) as dialogues
      from contributors c
        where c.visible = true
```

Another version

```
   select
      c.first_name,
      c.last_name,
      c.user_id,
      c.photo_url,
      s.dialogues
      from contributors c
        join (
          select count(*) dialogues, user_id from (
              select contributor_one_uuid user_id from dialogues
              union all 
              select contributor_two_uuid from dialogues
          ) stats group by user_id
        ) s on (s.user_id = c.user_id)
      where c.visible = true
```